# Is it good to install Linux on an external hard drive?

Tags: linux, hard-disk

I have an external hard drive. I would like to install Linux on it (I choose Fedora KDE).

I made a bootable DVD. I will choose the external hard drive to install Fedora on it.

Is it good to do this? My colleague told that it will be slow. Is there any alternatives?

Comment: Connected via what? Serial? Parallel? USB1? USB2? USB3? External S-ATA? "Hard drive" like in "spinning disks" or is it a SSD?

Comment: You should edit your question to tell much more about your computer and its hard drive (and how it is partitioned).

Comment: "Is xxx good" is not a question because "good" is entirely open ended and subjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon the hardware connection between the disk drive and the computer. But if it is an [USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) 2, indeed it would be slow (whatever OS you use).

The alternative could be to add a new hardware SATA drive, or to repartition your existing internal drive (to have some space for your Linux system). Perhaps you could repartition (& shrink the existing partitions) your drive to get e.g. 64GBytes of available space.

Before resizing partitions, don't forget to backup (on some external drive or USB key) your most important data files.

Another way might be to install Linux on a [VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine#System_virtual_machines) or an [hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor). Again, that is a bit slower than a native installation.